# Exibir dialogs quando der certo

Tags: php, ajax

Como faço para que apareça um Dialog quando o script ocorrer corretamente?

```
public function addDatabase($name, $collation) {
    // Checks whether all fields filled (Prevent future errors)
    if (!empty($name) AND !empty($collation)) {
        try {
            // If you want to change (Don't forget the ;)
            // http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-database.html
            $sql_query = 'CREATE DATABASE `'.$name.'` COLLATE `'.$collation.'`;';

            // Prepare the query to execute
            $query = $this->db->prepare($sql_query);

            // Execute the query
            $query->execute();
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            exit ('DB ERROR: '. $e->getMessage());
        }
    } else {
        if (empty($name)) {
            echo '$name está vazio';
        }
        if (empty($collation)) {
            echo '$collation está vazio';
        }
    }
}
```

CSS/JS do dialog: http://materializecss.com/dialogs.html

Answer (score 2):

Você está usando `PDO`? Modifique o código pra algo parecido com isso:

**Classe Dao**

```
try {
    // If you want to change (Don't forget the ;)
    // http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-database.html
    //$sql_query = 'CREATE DATABASE `'.$name.'` COLLATE `'.$collation.'`;';
    $sql_query = "CREATE DATABATE :name COLLATE :collation;";

    // Prepare the query to execute
    $query = $this->db->prepare($sql_query);

    $query->bindParam(":name", $name);
    $query->bindParam(":collation", $collation);

    // Execute the query
    $query->execute();
    $result = $query->rowCount();

    return $result > 0 ? true : false;
} catch() ....
```

**PHP que recebe a chamada do AJAX:**

```
$dao = new Dao();
$result = $dao->addDatabase("Foo", "Bar");

if ($result) {
    echo "success";
    exit();
} else {
    echo "error";
    exit();
}
```

**Javascript/jQuery:**

```
 $.ajax({
    url: 'ajax/script.php',
    ...
}).done(function(data) {
    if (data == 'success') {
        Materialize.toast('Sucesso!', 4000);
    } else {
        Materialize.toast('Ops, algo deu errado!', 4000)
    }
});
```

**Exemplo:** http://www.codeshare.io/oP1vO

Comment: " PHP que recebe a chamada do AJAX " Este ficaria em qual página? Dentro da form ? EDIT: Vou tentar colocar no controller.php pois ele que pega as informações do model

Comment: EDIT: Percebi que ele está retornando sucess e error. Porém não está aparecendo nenhum dialog no index. Code completo http://www.codeshare.io/LZKq0

Comment: Você não está mandando nada pelo ajax, atribua um `id` ao seu `form` e coloque essas linhas no seu ajax logo abaixo de `url: ..`, `type: 'POST', data: $('#seuform').serialize()`.

Comment: Code atualizado: Mais qual onde eu coloco o href e qual link? http://www.codeshare.io/LZKq0

Comment: Você vai precisar de um php pra receber os dados do seu form e instanciar a classe `Controller`, esse é o php que precisa ser colocado no parâmetro `url: ` do seu código js, vou fazer um exemplo aqui na minha máquina pra você ter uma visão completa. 4 arquivos serão usados (index.php, Controller.php, Model.php e outroarquivo.php)

Comment: Desculpa pela demora, fiquei sem computador. Mas, cadê o exemplo?

Answer (score 1):

Como você utilizou o `try`, tudo ao final do bloco irá rodar caso uma exceção não seja dispara. Para mostrar o aviso que você linkou no final da pergunta, pode usar o `echo` do PHP para imprimir um comando JavaScript:

```
public function addDatabase($name, $collation) {
    // Checks whether all fields filled (Prevent future errors)
    if (!empty($name) AND !empty($collation)) {
        try {
            // If you want to change (Don't forget the ;)
            // http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-database.html
            $sql_query = 'CREATE DATABASE `'.$name.'` COLLATE `'.$collation.'`;';

            // Prepare the query to execute
            $query = $this->db->prepare($sql_query);

            // Execute the query
            $query->execute();

            // Dá um aviso para o usuário
            echo "<script>Materialize.toast('Sucesso!', 4000)</script>";
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            // Caso aconteça algum erro, esse bloco é executado
            exit ('DB ERROR: '. $e->getMessage());
        }
    } else {
        [...]
}
```

Comment: Mas eu estou usando MVC, ou seja ele vai para outro link ao executar. Oque faço ?

Comment: Após o `$query->execute();` ele vai imediatamente para outro lugar? Não termina de executar o bloco? Uma alternativa seria colocar a mensagem nesse outro link, porém como não sei como ele funciona, não tem como lhe ajudar.

Comment: Após preencher todos os dados é enviado para outra página, processa e volta para a página inicial.